# Adjust Terminal - (Arch-like Info-Screen)

Tags: command-line

I use Ubuntu for many years but recently I discovered a nice feature in Arch. It is common to display system-information on headless servers on ssh-login, on Ubuntu its the landscape- package.

I wounded if it's possible to create the same for the normal terminal in Ubuntu . Like the terminal in Arch

[image]

I think it might be useful to have this information displayed, at the time one starts the terminal.

Is it possible to create something like this for the terminal, and if so what would you suggest? I tried motd but these messages were not displayed. 
Daniel

Comment: aking1012 - no it does not. I am not talking about SSH-Login but I talk about the Terminal when I start it from Unity - When I do so I don't want to see just my name@computer: but something like in Arch. I adjusted motd.tail and motd and nothing was shown.

Comment: you still have to add it to bashrc

Answer (score 2):

You say you've already got the MOTD part set up, so now it's just:
`echo 'cat /etc/motd' >> ~/.bashrc`

A brief aside, you get this:
[image]
If you install Ubuntu 11.10 server.  If you're migrating from arch, I suspect you may be more comfortable with adding to a server install instead of installing ubuntu-desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The application that display the system info in Arch is called Archey and it can be installed on Ubuntu. This website has instruction on how to do so.

http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/02/how-to-install-screenfetch-and-archey.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit .bashrc

Here are some useful links in regards to what you can add:

- http://mostlycli.blogspot.com/2010/03/my-bashrc-file-part-2-useful-system.html
- http://usalug.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=10456
- http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2008-01/msg01947.html
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-large-colorful-text-banner-on-screen/

To find more do a Google search on cool .bashrc welcome screens

Answer (score 0):

There's a program that does this that's called [linuxlogo [image: Install linuxlogo]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linuxlogo), here's the homepage:

- http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/linux_logo/

You can install it and then just run `linuxlogo` for a default debian manner, check the manpage for all the configuration options to get what you need.